# Why seaborn kdeplot is not showing the expected output?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib as plt
sns.kdeplot(x, shade=True, color="red")
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

I have an array whose value ranges from 0.8 to 1.0 and what I'll want is to have a sort of bell curve to fit it, but I'm not capable to get this. The problem is my data or something else? Here is the output I get: [image]

Comment: Can you post the data that is in x, or at least a subset of it?

Comment: It's a lot of data. The majority are 1.0 but occasionally I have values which range like above

Comment: Got it.  I notice that the code above won't run as-is (`matplotlib` should be `matplotlib.pyplot`)  I'm not saying this to be pedantic, it just makes me wonder what code actually produced the graph above.  When I fix the issue and run it with my own `x` it works as expected.  Suggest starting fresh and pass only a part of `x`, e.g. `sns.kdeplot(x[0:200], ...)` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: A kde plot is meant for a continuous distribution. The post seems to use a discrete distribution, maybe 60 numbers in steps of 1/300?